# What is the way to remove a git submodule as of git version 1.9.3?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

as of git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)  on mac how do i remove a git submodule? I am reading alot of outdated information with many developers telling me they wont work.  What is the current way ?
 will `git deinit pathToSubModule`    do the trick ?

The steps i thought would work are [here](http://davidwalsh.name/git-remove-submodule) but comments say they wont.

Let me explain my current situation and what i need accomplished.  I've installed [the Quick repository](https://github.com/Quick/Quick#how-to-install-quick) and added it to as submodule to my project.  This code is already checked in and others are using it.  What i now need to do is *fork* the same Quick repository and host it on a more secure github that my company has (so a completely other private github). After forking it i want to add that fork as a gitSubmodule and let it replace the current Quick submodule i had installed previously.

update: i've read that the following is the correct way on latest git version please confirm?

```
To remove a submodule added using:

git submodule add blah@blah.com:repos/blah.git lib/blah
Run:

git rm lib/blah
That's it.

For old versions of git (circa ~1.8.5) use:

git submodule deinit lib/blah
git rm lib/blah
git config -f .gitmodules --remove-section submodule.lib/blah
```

Comment: I've wrestled submodule problems for two days. The breakthrough came when I found this: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13102. Basically, Xcode, and perhaps other apps, struggle to expand url's containing '~'. Once I changed ssh://username@server.remoteHost.com/~/git/MyRepo.git to ssh://username@server.remoteHost.com/home/username/git/MyRepo.git (look up the actual path on your server), all the weirdness disappeared with ten minutes.

Answer (score 222, accepted):

You have the `git submodule deinit`

```
git submodule deinit <asubmodule>    
git rm <asubmodule>
# Note: asubmodule (no trailing slash)
# or, if you want to leave it in your working tree
git rm --cached <asubmodule>
rm -rf .git/modules/<asubmodule>
```

---

### ***`deinit`***

> Un-register the given submodules, i.e. **remove the whole `submodule.$name`**
>     section from `.git/config` together with their work tree.
>
> Further calls to `git submodule update`, `git submodule foreach` and `git submodule sync` will **skip** any unregistered submodules until they are initialized again, so use this command if you don’t want to have a local checkout of the submodule in your work tree anymore.
>
> If you really want to remove a submodule from the repository and commit that use `git rm` instead.
>
> If `--force` is specified, the submodule’s work tree will be removed even if it contains local modifications.

Comment: i want to completely wipe out the submodule for me and the other users as well. So all i need is git submodule deinit asubmodule; and    
git rm asubmodule ?? Also what about the other users cached submodule, would they have to delete it after pulling down ?

Comment: I wanted to delete the local copy of the submodule and this worked perfect, all the files in the subdir are gone.

Comment: You may also need `rm -rf <asubmodule>` if you've already checked out a version of the base repository which has un-registered the submodule.

Answer (score 16):

I'm using Git version 2.16.2 and `git rm` does the job mostly well:

```
git rm path-to-submodule
```

You can verify with `git status` and `git diff --cached` that this deinitializes the submodule and modifies `.gitmodules` automatically. As always, you need to commit the change.

However, even though the submodule is removed from source control, `.git/modules/path-to-submodule` still contains the submodule repository and `.git/config` contains its URL, so you still have to remove those manually:

```
git config --remove-section submodule.path-to-submodule
rm -rf .git/modules/path-to-submodule
```

Keeping the submodule repository and configuration is intentional so that you can undo the removal with e.g. `git reset --hard`.

Comment: most recent answer and the shortest solution

Answer (score 4):

## How to safely remove a submodule.

(adds to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1260982/342794)

1. List and locate the submodule section in `.gitmodules` file. Say via terminal `vi .gitmodules`. Example:

   ```
   [submodule "submodules/afnetworking"]
       path = submodules/afnetworking
       url = https://github.com/CompanyName/afnetworking.git
   ```
2. Submodules can be used with local forks. For a long running projects, code may differ from original repo and might have some fixes. It's a good idea to verify if submodule code went through changes over the course of project. Example: Look at the logs, if it's pointing to `master` branch or some local branch. exploring git logs to find modifications that were done via terminal. typically these are stored under a directory, my example, under `submodules` directory.

   ```
   User$ cd submodules/afnetworking
   User$ git log
   ```
3. Remove the submodule section from .gitmodules, save the file. Example: `git status` should show only following as modified

   ```
   modified:   .gitmodules
   ```
4. Stage the changes with `git add .gitmodules`.
5. List and locate the submodule section in `.git/config` files. Say via terminal `vi .git/config`. Example:

   ```
   [submodule "submodules/afnetworking"]
       url = https://github.com/CompanyName/afnetworking.git
   ```
6. Remove the git cache sobmodule files. running `git rm --cached submodules/afnetworking` (no trailing slash) would remove it successfully. Example:

   ```
   User$ git rm --cached submodules/afnetworking
   rm 'submodules/afnetworking'    <-- terminal output
   ```
7. Remove the submodule files under `.git` directory with `rm -rf .git/modules/...`. Confirm it with `git status` afterwards.

   ```
   User$ rm -rf .git/modules/submodules/afnetworking/
   User$ git status
   On branch feature/replace-afnetworking-submodule-with-pod
   Changes to be committed:
     (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
       modified:   .gitmodules
       deleted:    submodules/afnetworking
   Untracked files:
     (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
       submodules/afnetworking/
   ```
8. Commit the changes. Confirm with `git status` afterwards.

   ```
   User$ git commit -m "Remove submodule afnetworking"
   [feature/replace-afnetworking-submodule-with-pod 70e239222] Remove submodule afnetworking
   2 files changed, 4 deletions(-)
     delete mode 160000 submodules/afnetworking
   User$ git status
   On branch feature/replace-afnetworking-submodule-with-pod
   Untracked files:
     (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
       submodules/afnetworking/
   nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
   ```
9. Delete the untracked submodule files.

   ```
   User$ rm -rf submodules/afnetworking
   ```
10. Delete the references from Xcode project. Build, fix compile and runtime issues.