# How to delete Black hidden folder in GitHub repo

Tags: git, github

This is first time I am using Git. In Git, I tried to commit some files. I had to force commit as some conflicts was arising. But When I checked it online a Black folder was present there (In the given figure its **ADME**). This seems like hidden folder. Now I want to remove this folder. But don't know how to do it. Please help.
   Note:- I had committed all the files at same moment.

[image: Git image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the current way to remove a git submodule?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850029/what-is-the-current-way-to-remove-a-git-submodule)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a submodule. to remove it do the following:

Delete relevant line from the .gitmodules file

Delete relevant section from .git/config

Run git rm --cached path_to_submodule (no trailing slash)

Commit and delete the now untracked submodule files.