# Github grey/unclickable directory

Tags: github, git-submodules

This is apparently a submodule directory. I am suppose to have a .submodule folder or/and a .git folder within the directory of that app which I don't.  (I can see all hidden files on finder) I pull and push and everything is up-to-date.

[image]

Info from: [GitHub projects "un-clickable" in repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909352/github-projects-un-clickable-in-repo)

I have done `git remote -v` it shows to my only repo I have.

Info from: [What does a grey icon in remote GitHub mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584255/what-does-a-grey-icon-in-remote-github-mean)

Interestingly when I do this command in my repo `git submodule update --init` it is referencing the app that has a problem `No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'Capstone Blog'`

Info from: [What is this grey git icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412396/what-is-this-grey-git-icon)

Also When I do `git submodule deinit .` it know which app has the problem. `No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'Capstone Blog'`

Info from: [What is the current way to remove a git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850029/what-is-the-current-way-to-remove-a-git-submodule/29850245)

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: :) I would like to have that folder clickable so people can view it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the problem was caused because I copied the entire directory which once had a .git file and maybe some other git files. I removed these files after I copied them into my new repo. Which did not do anything and I was still having the same problem. So here is what I did.

1. I completely removed that directory using `rm -rf Capstone\ Blog/`.
2. Then I copied all the files in the Capstone EXCEPT for the .git files.

Now its working

Answer (score 0):

I made 2 repos, repo1 and repo2. Added a file and pushed them both to github.

```
cd repo1
git submodule add git://clone/url/for/repo2.git
git add .
git commit -m "Adding repo2"
git push origin master
```

Results:

[image]

Content of .gitmodules:

```
[submodule "repo2"]
    path = repo2
    url = git@path/to/repo2.git
```

It bears asking: Is Capstone Blog available on github?

Comment: I am not sure what your asking. Capestone should be available and is not currently available on github. It should not be submodule directory, it should be a normal folder like all the others (maybe because I copy pasted the entire directory from another repo(BitBucket)).